# Hash retrieval from URL

Tags: javascript, fragment-identifier

I am trying to setup a form which grabs the hash from the url, then uses that value to determine what radio inputs to check. The latter part is working, but i cannot get the hash retrieval to work.

```
var url = document.referrer;
var dec= decodeURIComponent(url.replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('?')+1);
var hash = decodeURI(hash);
```

In firefox console, i try 'console.log(hash)', and simply get a Reference Error saying that 'hash is not defined'.

The entire script is here if needed - http://pastebin.com/Yq9NbHyz

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hash"? At first I thought you meant the fragment identifier (`#foo`) but your code is looking for `?`.

Comment: I am simply using '?' instead of '#' for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: ... what? What do you mean, aesthetic reasons? They're different characters!

Answer (score 0):

Because `hash` is not global variable. Use `window.location.hash` or `location.hash`

Comment: If you meant adding it in the if statement, then it solved the reference error, but it is still saying that 'hash' is undefined. Why would this be?